# Is it possible to make this topology into a rectangle shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Is it possible to make this topology into a square without twisting, rotating the vertices to get a perfect square? I know my mesh because of the circle in the middle has gone into a circular topology, but some parts I need them to be rectangle shape. So if there's an easier method I'd like to know, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have such topology just a bit outter :)

[image]

So you can delete few unnecessary loops and reposition the square.
Straighten with S, x or Y, zero if needed (as already mentioned).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If at all possible, I would work the other way round, without the circular topo.. It's easier to make a square region circular, than to make a quarter-circle square.

[image]

- Grid
- Inset squares (you could make them bigger first, if wanted)
- Scale out a region to accommodate a circle
- Shipped add-on: *Loop Tools* > Circle the inner region, and inset the circle.

If you needed supporting loops for extrusion and subdivision, or other hand work, you could work under a Mirror in X and Y

Answer (score 2):

First rotate your whole geometry by 45°:
[image]

Then scale the side edges by 0 along y and x accordingly to straighten them up:
[image]

Finally rotate the whole geometry back:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with custom transform orientations.

Select one of the edges pointing towards the circle's center. Above the viewport (a dropdown that says "Global") add a new orientation with a "+" button. The Y axis is now pointed along the selected edge. So now select the edges you want to be perpendicular to it, and flatten them along the new orientation's Y (press S, then Y, then 0, then Enter).

Now that you've flattened the perpendicular sides, you can use them as a second new transform orientation. So again click "+", and now flatten the other two sides along the new Y.

If you want a *perfect square*, you can do a two-segment vertex bevel, but you'll need right angles between edges at the vertex.
[image]

Comment: Wow, all great solutions, which one can I really mark as correct. They all worked well to solve my problem.